# Confusion About Yesod Widget Related Types

Tags: haskell, yesod, hamlet

I have just started playing with Yesod, and although I can already get some interesting results, I am struggling understanding clearly some of its types (maybe because I am not familiar with Template Haskell).

The [usual way](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/widgets#widgets_constructing_widgets) to pass a hamlet snippet to the defaultLayout function is via the toWidget function. So following the definitions of ham1 and ham2 below, the proper instructions within defaultLayout are respectively `toWidget ham1` and `ham2`.

**My question:** In the following (working) code why does the instruction `toWidget ham2` compile, while it is a very different animal from ham1? I guess that it means that both ham1's type (`ham1 :: t -> Text.Blaze.Internal.Markup` **(*)**) and ham2's type (`ham2 :: Widget`) are instances of the ToWidget class but that's not completely obvious to me when reading this [class' instance definitions](http://haddock.stackage.org/nightly-2016-01-05/yesod-core-1.4.18.1/Yesod-Core-Widget.html#t:ToWidget).

**(*)** Also, it'd be great if someone could let me know if there is a "nicer" type synonym than `t -> Text.Blaze.Internal.Markup` for ham1.

Code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

module Main where

import Yesod
import Text.Blaze.Internal (Markup)

data App = App
instance Yesod App

mkYesod "App" [parseRoutes|
/ HomeR GET
|]

getHomeR :: Handler Html
getHomeR = defaultLayout $ do
    setTitle "Some Title"

    toWidget ham1   -- usual way to produce a Widget from hamlet snippet
    toWidget ham2   -- ??
    ham2            -- already of type Widget


ham1 :: t -> Text.Blaze.Internal.Markup -- explicit signature for reference only
ham1 = [hamlet|
<h1> 1) Hello
<h2> World!
 |]

ham2 :: Widget
ham2 = 
    toWidget [hamlet|
<h1> 2) Hello
<h2> World!
 |]

main :: IO ()
main = do
    warp 3000 App
```

Output :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure what's being asked, so I'll just explain how it works,
I hope it'll be relevant.

`defaultLayout` takes a widget to put it in well… default layout. Thus your
`do`-block combines widgets monadically. To pass type-checker, every line in
that `do`-block should be of type `Widget a` (or `WidgetT App IO a`, is your
site's data type is `App`). Instances of `ToWidget` are things that can be
transformed to widgets. `Widget`s are instances of this type class, as well
as `render -> Html` things. Given that `Html` is a type synonym for
`Text.Blaze.Internal.Markup`, your `ham1` is a perfect candidate to be
passed to `toWidget`, see in source code:

```
instance render ~ RY site => ToWidget site (render -> Html) where
    toWidget x = …
```

`(~)` puts additional constraint, it tells type checker (after this instance
is already chosen by it) that by the way `render` must have type `RY site`.
`site` a phantom type, it ensures that different parts of system
belong to the same site, it's usually `App` if you're using scaffolding.
`RY site` uses another type-synonym `RY` passing it `site` variable, it results
in type like this:

```
Route App -> [(Text, Text)] -> Text
```

This is the type of argument `ham1` takes.

So those instances allow you to transform different things into widgets,
including functions like that produced by `hamlet` quasi-quoter, no magic
here.

Comment: Thanks Mark. Apologies if my question is not very clear, but among the code's three consecutive instructions : `toWidget ham1`, `toWidget ham2` and `ham2`, `toWidget ham2` is the one I do not understand, type-wise, since ham2 is already defined as a `toWidget something` type, so `toWidget ham2` seems to "compound" toWidget twice into a `toWidget (toWidget something)`. (I'll try to find ways to clarify my question and will edit it)

Comment: @JeanAnthelme, `Widget` is instance of `ToWidget` (which may be consfusing from certain point of view), so you can do `toWidget widget` where `widget` is already a `Widget`.

Comment: thanks. Yes I agree, and my question is equivalent to "is Widget an instance of ToWidget", which I could not understand immediately from ToWidget's instance definition, but you put me on the right tracks and I'll go through it again.